# Check if a string is preceded by a certain character

Tags: javascript, string

This is my code:

```
if (consoles.toLowerCase().indexOf("nes")!=-1)
    document.write('<img class="icon_nes" src="/images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1">'); 
if (consoles.toLowerCase().indexOf("snes")!=-1)
    document.write('<img class="icon_snes" src="/images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1">');
```

When the words "nes" and/or "snes" are inside the string "consoles", it's supposed to output their respective icon. If both consoles are inside the string,  both icons should appear.

This obviously doesn't work, because "nes" is also contained inside "snes".

So, is there a way to check if "nes" is preceded by an S?

Keep in mind that "nes" may not be the first word in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you'd better test if "nes" or "snes" appear *as a word*:

```
if (/\bnes\b/i.test(consoles)) 
  ...

if (/\bsnes\b/i.test(consoles)) 
  ...
```

`\b` in those [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) are *word boundaries* and the `i` means that they're case insensitive.

Now if you really want to test if "nes" but not preceded by a "s" is in your string, you may use

```
if (/[^s]nes/i.test(consoles))
```

Comment: Answer being use a regular expression. `\b` being word breaks

Answer (score 1):

check if nes is in position 0 || consoles[index - 1] != 's'

Answer (score 0):

My own approach would be to use `replace()`, using its callback function:

```
var str = "some text nes some more text snes",
    image = document.createElement('img');

str.replace(/nes/gi, function (a,b,c) {
    // a is the matched substring,
    // b is the index at which that substring was found,
    // c is the string upon which 'replace()' is operating.
    if (c.charAt(b-1).toLowerCase() == 's') {
        // found snes or SNES
        img = image.cloneNode();
        document.body.appendChild(img);
        img.src = 'http://path.to/snes-image.png';
    }
    else {
        // found nes or NES
        img = image.cloneNode();
        document.body.appendChild(img);
        img.src = 'http://path.to/nes-image.png';
    }
    return a;
});
```

References:

- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).
- [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode).
- [`String.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 0):

`"snes".match(/([^s]|^)nes/)

=> null`

"nes".match(/([~s]|^)nes/)
=> nes

Comment: Please explain why that would work instead of just giving the answer.

Comment: This will give any line that has nes (but not snes)

Answer (score 0):

basic way to check if a letter is before the substring.

```
var index = consoles.toLowerCase().indexOf("nes");
if(index != -1 && consoles.charAt(index-1) != "s"){
    //your code here for nes
}
if(index != -1 && consoles.charAt(index-1) == "s"){
    //your code here for snes
}
```

Note:  you should do checking to make sure you don't push index out of  bounds... (string starts with "nes" will cause error)